# Should we add screenshots?

Tags: discussion, asking

At least for [game-rec](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-rec) and [identify-this-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-game) answers this would help a lot... I'll put this to vote (edited following Oak's advice)

Comment: @Oak♦: done. Though I probably took you too literally...

Comment: Watch out for copyright! (Yes, I know, I'm a broken disk.) Screenshots hotlinked from Wikipedia are fine.

Comment: @badp: I hope free advertisement falls under fair use. Or do you consider the screenshotter as potential troublemaker?

Comment: @Tobias, don't you think Wikipedia also does "free advertisement" with their articles? Please keep in mind that, at some point, this site will start getting ads -- which Wikipedia does not. :)

Comment: @badp I understand your concern, but I'm pretty certain screenshots easily fall under "fair use" in US law (where this site is hosted). There are gazillion sites out there which have screenshots of games, and I've never heard of that being a violation of any sort.

Comment: For me is ok, but consider the size of the screenshot. Maybe we can decide for a rule that only screeshots inside WWxHH are accepted (e.g. 640x480)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Screenshots are awesome, especially for the type of questions listed in the question. I'm not sure there is a need to actively encourage them, though, because I think people have a tendency to upvote answers with screenshots anyway.

Also, I do not think we should edit other people's answers just to add screenshots... unless it's a community wiki answer, at least.

Comment: +1. However, don't forget the freehand circle bonus as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, especially for [game-rec](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-rec)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, especially for [identify-this-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-game)